# SSAS cube restrict data source by role

Tags: sql, ssas, sql-server-data-tools

I have a data source for a SSAS Multi-dimensional (MOLAP) cube that has a column called `RegionId` where the value will be 
`1, 2, 3 or 4`

I then have some user roles in SSAS where I want to restrict the data a user will see in a measure group by a single RegionId i.e. 1.

Example:

`RegionId = 1, Week = 1, Value = 500
RegionId = 1, Week = 1, Value = 700
RegionId = 2, Week = 1, Value = 300
RegionId = 3, Week = 1, Value = 500`

If a `Region 1` user were to view this data in the cube and group the data by the `Week = 1` then they should see a total of `700 + 500 = 1200` Not the total across all regions.

There is a way to restrict the data they can select in a `dimension` but if they were to use the time dimension ONLY then they would see values in their `measures group` that are not related to their specific region.

I believe this sort of thing is called `row level security`? However I have not found a clear way to do this for a Multi-dimensional cube, only in Tabular.. which I am not using.

Anyone know how this can be achieved? easily using the roles permission settings? Can this be done in the role's cell data tab using some MDX ? if so please can you provide an example of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cube will return only region related data if you check the visual totals box as explained here: http://easyroles.com/2014/02/visual-totals-in-ssas-security/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that particular example is used on a dimension that has been restricted. What happens when the user uses a dimension such as "time" where it will not be restricted?

Comment: Visual totals makes sure that role context is considered no matter what you query. So even though role playing dimension is completely left out, values will be recalculated for total sum of your access rights.

Comment: Just to help me understand. I also have a `region` dimension that is assigned to all of my measure groups. If I was to set the `dimension data` for a role to deselect all 4 regions and select only region 1, as well as the visual totals checkbox; then a user assigned to that role would not see the full data for a measure group even when they are not using that `region` dimension in the cube? i.e. just viewing weekly totals.. is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Correct. The Region dimension is still conceptually present, but its current member is the "All Region" member -- and Visual Totals for the security on the Region dimension still kicks in for the "All Region" member.

So rows in the measure group will be filtered by the security defined on the Region dimension even though Region isn't explicitly used in the MDX query.

Comment: Thanks I'll give this all a go and see how it goes